# How to start an overlay activity over *other* apps?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android app which needs to run an overlay activity with some content in it over other apps on the phone at the moment they start or get focused. For this, I use `AccessiblityService`:

```
    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        if (event.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
           if (cond1) {
              
              // (!)
              // this will get triggered properly
              //

             val intent = Intent(this, MyOverlayActivity::class.java)
             intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP


             startActivity(intent)
           }
        }
    }
```

However, it'll only get *launched properly* whenever I switch to my own activity - `MainActivity`.

**What's the matter?**

MyOverlayActivity:

```
    class MyOverlayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            // 1
    //        window.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY)
    //        val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    //            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    //            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    //            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    //            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    //            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    //        )
    //        window.attributes = layoutParams
            //



            // 2
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            )
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
            window.setLayout(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
            //


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_overlay_layout)
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
    <!-- [.............] -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<!-- [.............] -->
    <activity android:name=".MyOverlayActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TranslucentNoTitleBarFullscreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation">
    </activity>
```

Note I've given the permission required to my app in Acessibility.

MinSdk = 31

Comment: "which needs to run an overlay activity" -- why do you believe that it needs to be an activity?

Comment: @CommonsWare there's a third-party lib that'll then load  some content onto `MyOverlayActivity`. A library requires an Activity rather than a view or window. So, preferably that it be in an Activity. However, *for now* even a window will do too

Comment: "A library requires an Activity rather than a view or window" -- I suspect that you will need to find another library, then, or ask the library's developers to modernize their API. "However, for now even a window will do too" -- there have been many posts written about how to display a window from a service, such as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67063026/115145).

Comment: @CommonsWare I suspect that you've given advince of which you've never been asked

Comment: What you are seeking -- an "overlay activity" -- is not really a thing. This is why I asked, in [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78207721/how-to-start-an-overlay-activity-over-other-apps?noredirect=1#comment137878514_78207721), why you felt that you needed an activity. [Your response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78207721/how-to-start-an-overlay-activity-over-other-apps?noredirect=1#comment137878553_78207721) was that a library required an activity. Hence, you need to replace or improve that library, to avoid that activity requirement.

Comment: @CommonsWare zero of helpful information.